# How to delay a function to allow it fully load

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a page which is dynamic, it was populated by an ajax call, like this:

```
function loadpage() {
          var container = document.querySelector(".container");

          var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.open('GET', ("data.html"), true);
          xhr.addEventListener("load", function(){
            container.innerHTML = xhr.response; 
            var noticeBar = document.querySelector("#noticeBar"); //this is from data.html which was jsut loaded into the DOM.        
        });
        xhr.send();
    }
```

when i do something like:

```
 function xyz(){
  loadPage().
  noticeBar.innerHTML = "bla bla bla"; //this will not work because the DOM hasnt been fully loaded

}
```

I am looking for a way to make it synchronous.

Comment: no you're not. Just call xyz when your XHR succeeds so that you set the noticebar text once you have the data that you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a callback parameter to `loadpage()`:

```
function loadpage(callback) {
      var container = document.querySelector(".container");

      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('GET', ("data.html"), true);
      xhr.addEventListener("load", function(){
        container.innerHTML = xhr.response; 
        var noticeBar = document.querySelector("#noticeBar"); //this is from data.html which was jsut loaded into the DOM.     
        callback(noticeBar);   
    });
    xhr.send();
}
```

and pass in a callback function:

```
function xyz(){
  loadpage(
    function(noticeBar) {
      noticeBar.innerHTML = "blah blah blah";
    }
  );
}
```